# How to set port for Rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack

builder.rb:

```
def app
  Rack::Builder.new do
    run App.new
  end.to_app
end
```

How to run on a given port?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
Rack::Handler.default.run(app, :Port => 3000)
```

Although it would be more typical to run your app in a `config.ru` file and specify port as a command line option to `rackup`, e.g.: `rackup -p 3000`.

Comment: What if you want to use a middleware before the app?

Comment: You would probably want to do that inside your `Rack::Builder.new` block. Both `Rack::Handler::<server>.run` and a `run` statement inside `config.ru` are going to block further script processing to respond to HTTP requests.

Comment: How do you figure this stuff out?

Comment: Glancing at your profile it seems like you have a pretty solid grasp of how Rack works! My limited knowledge of Rack comes mostly from reading the source code of [Rack-Contrib](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib) (most of these utilities are short and easy to follow), and [Cuba](https://github.com/soveran/cuba), and reading a handful of articles online on Rack Middleware and how to use Rack directly. I don't know where I discovered `Handler.run` initially...

Comment: I wish I had a solid grasp! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

When you `rackup` just specify it with option `-p` so:

`rackup -p 8808` would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this in `config.ru` like so:

```
#config.ru
Dir.glob('./app/{models,helpers}/*.rb').each { |file| require file }
require './app/main'
Rackup::Handler.default.run(MySuperBlog::API, :Port => 2300)
```

and then in the terminal:

```
> rackup
```

And if you use rack unreloader:

```
require 'rack/unreloader'

Unreloader = Rack::Unreloader.new(:subclasses=>%w'MySuperBlog'){MySuperBlog::API}
Unreloader.require './app/main.rb'
Rack::Handler.default.run(Unreloader, :Port => 2300)
```