# How to use standard library to parse URL params in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, webserver

I am using the following code with "uri" and "CGI" to parse the params of the URL:

```
require 'socket'
require 'uri'
require 'CGI'

server = TCPServer.new 8888

while session = server.accept
  request = session.gets

  p "request", request

  url = "http://somewebsite.com" + request.sub("GET ", "").sub(" HTTP/1.1", "").gsub(/(\r|\n)/, "")
  uri = URI(url)
  params = CGI.parse(uri.query)

  p "params", params

  session.print "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n" # 1
  session.print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" # 2
  session.print "\r\n" # 3

  session.print "Hello world! The time is #{Time.now}" #4

  session.close
end
```

I had to "make up" a full URL by adding the `http://somewebsite.com` to the path, and use `uri` and `CGI` functions to do it.  If the browser uses http://localhost:8888/?a=123&b=hello  then it works well. But if the browser tried to access http://localhost:8888/favicon.ico or http://localhost:8888 then it broke right away, saying cannot split. (failing at `CGI.parse(uri.query)`)

I can change the line to

```
params = uri.query ? CGI.parse(uri.query) : nil
```

but the whole thing seems a bit hacky, needing to make up a URL and then `CGI.parse` would break if query doesn't exist. Is there actually a better way to use standard library to do it? (should something else be used instead of `uri` and `CGI`?)

(Using standard library has the advantage of automatically handling the cases for `%20` and multiple params as in http://localhost:8888/?a=123&b=hello%20world&b=good, giving

```
{"a"=>["123"], "b"=>["hello world", "good"]}
```

as the result.)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to make up anything? You don't need a full URI to use `CGI.parse`.  Something like this should work:

```
require 'socket'
require 'CGI'

server = TCPServer.new 8888

while session = server.accept
  request = session.gets

  method, full_path = request.split(' ')
  path, params = full_path.split('?')

  params = CGI.parse(params.gsub('?','')) if params

  session.print "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n" # 1
  session.print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" # 2
  session.print "\r\n" # 3
  session.print "Hello world! The time is #{Time.now}" #4
  session.print "\nparams: #{params}"

  p "params:", params

  session.close
end
```

Comment: it seems a bit low level to split by space and then by `?`... but I guess it works and there is no exception cases... would it work better if there were something like `method, path, params, protocol = CGI.split_request(request)` (does it belong to `CGI`)?

Comment: by the way, instead of using `TCPServer.new 8888`, we can also use the one line start up of WeBrick, and be able to use `foo.cgi` and run a Ruby program... in this case `cgi_request = CGI::new("html4");` and `cgi_request.params` will be ready to use

Comment: There's no set rule for how you want to parse the `session.gets` which comes in as just a string. Do whatever works best for your use case. In earlier version of my answer I had `method, _, params, protocol, version = request.split(/[\s\/]/)`.

Comment: @nopole are you proposing and answer to your own question in your comment here?

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use Rack if you don't want to learn about reinventing the CGI wheel. Rack is not technically part of the standard library but is as close as you get.

```
# Gemfile.rb
gem 'rack'
```

run `$ bundle install`.

```
# application.rb
class Application
  # This is the main entry point for Rack
  # @param env [Hash]
  # @return [Array] status, headers, body
  # @see https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request
  # @see https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Response
  def self.call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    Rack::Response.new(
      "Hello " + request.params["name"] || "World",
      200,
      { "Content-Type" => "text/plain" }
    ).finish
  end
end
```

`request.params` is a hash that contains query string parameters and parameters from the request body for POST requests.

```
# config.ru
require 'rack'
require_relative 'application'
run Application
```

Run `$ rackup` to start the server.

Comment: This should fall back to webrick. You can also use thin or puma by adding the gems to the Gemfile.

Comment: is `thin` or `puma` better than `webrick`? I saw webrick started by the local file is not served -- how to make it serve local files?

Comment: it seems it needs to be (1) `"Hello " + (request.params["name"] || "World")` (2) `require './application'`  and can you specify the port in the code instead of starting up `rackup -p 8888`?

Comment: Webrick isn't really the greatest at anything. I would really recommend puma.  I think you can specify the port by `run Application, port: 8888` but is usually done by setting up a Procfile instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594945/how-to-set-port-for-rack-app

Comment: The parens don't really do anything in `"Hello " + (request.params["name"] || "World")`. `+` in ruby is actually a method so `"Hello " + request.params["name"] || "World"` evalautes `request.params["name"] || "World"` first anyways.

Comment: it will error out if no param in URL, saying string + nil is not possible